# Reading JSON files local to the website in JS via direct path

Tags: javascript, html, json

It remains a challenge to embed local json files into a website and be able to read their contents via JavaScript. I used to do it with XMLHttpRequest but this stopped working, I tried the newer fetch method but that also fails; Either because it doesn't understand local paths or because of that CORS garbage (sorry I just absolutely hate CORS by now). I won't create a local webserver just to test / develop a standalone project, I want it to work anywhere including when opened directly.

I know this was asked many times and in different forms. But what's presently the easiest way to embed a JSON file into a site and have it work via local URL (eg: "/json/mydata.json"),  without running into CORS or path errors, in a simple way that works with all major browsers? Do I even need a networking function to fetch the file in the first place or, more ideally, could I include it via a HTML notation the same way you do with scripts in a form such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" src="json/data.json"></script>
```

This seems more ideal but I'm not aware of it being possible: HTML doesn't let you embed json files the way you can a CSS file, and even if it did I don't know how JS would extract the content. At worst I'll declare my JSON in a JS script and embed that... I dislike this idea though as it's not pure json then but a script file containing one JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, haven't solved the actual issue but found an acceptable way around it: I went ahead and simply implemented my JSON objects as jsonp calls. This felt acceptable given JSONP is an established standard, and with the orderly way HTML links scripts its functionality fits like a glove.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="json/data.json"></script>
</body>
```

init.js:

```
// callback for jsonp
function jsonp_parse(data) {
    alert(data.test);
}
```

data.json:

```
jsonp_parse({
    "test":"1234"
});
```

Comment: Re: _"JSONP is an established standard"_ It's a well-known technique, certainly. We probably shouldn't go as far as to declare it an _established standard_. +1, nevertheless. JSONP can be a useful fall-back.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique pioneered (in 2019 or before) by **Scott Jehl** of the **Filament Group** (see: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/html-includes/) which cleverly enables an HTML document to import:

- **HTML**
- **SVG**
- **JSON**
- **plaintext** etc.

This is the basic technique:

```
<object data="json/data.json" style="display: none;" onload="this.before(this.contentDocument.children[0]); this.remove();"></object>
```

If you wish, you may elaborate the script inside the `onload` attribute so that it imports the JSON into a `<div>` element, a `<script>` element etc.

---

If you would prefer not to use inline `style` and `onload` attributes, you can adopt an unobtrusive approach, instead:

**HTML:**

```
<object class="json-import-helper" data="json/data.json"></object>
```

**CSS:**

```
.json-import-helper {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const jsonImportHelper = document.getElementsByClassName('json-import-helper')[0];

const importJSON = (e) => {
  e.target.before(e.target.contentDocument.children[0]);
  e.target.remove();
}

jsonImportHelper.addEventListener('load', importJSON);
```

Comment: Interesting method. A bit too unusual for my liking but worth taking note of. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I don't disagree, @MirceaKitsune, it's pretty unorthodox. I guess we're all waiting for a standard way to import JSON, HTML etc. _HTML Imports_ have been abandoned and we've some time to wait before _HTML Modules_ happen. Separately from the approach above, I've tried my hand at an [importJSON function](https://github.com/RouninMedia/importJSON-for-Ashiva).